# 100% width div scrollbar

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'm making a webpage with a fixed background and a scrollable centered text.

I first set the html and body style:

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

and then comes the page:

```
<body>
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:0;">
<img src="background.jpg" align="center" width="100%" height="100%" />
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:auto; z-index:1;">
```

Under Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Opera works great. Under IE8 (i don't have the chance, neither i do really want, to test under IE7, IE9 and so on...) are displayed two vertical scrollbars one next to the other:

[image]

Is there a solution to this crap?

Comment: for us to check and see your code , instead of guessing how it works , there is an online tool which you can paste your code there and share the saved link to us. so that we opene it and see and revision the code to a fixed version via a new url which keeps incrementing jsfiddle.com  or jsbin.com.

Comment: Now do i have to look for changes at that link?

Comment: no. if someone edit or add things , he will send you a new link in a form of :  ( which generated automatically) : jsfiddle.com/GmrWv/1 .....jsfiddle.com/GmrWv/2......jsfiddle.com/GmrWv/3...... etc

Comment: I have IE 9 and Jsfiddle only works/displays with compatibility mode on... But I don't see two scrollbars I'm afraid.

Comment: Have you tried using `overflow:auto;`?